# RegisterMultiple does not keep implementation type as singleton if registered as multiple registration types?

Tags: nancy, tinyioc

I am trying to add a type called **TypeA** as two different registration types: **InterfaceA** and **InterfaceB**.

```
container.RegisterMultiple(typeof(InterfaceA), new[] {typeof(TypeA), typeof(TypeB)});
container.RegisterMultiple(typeof(InterfaceB), new[] {typeof(TypeA), typeof(TypeC)});
```

But when I Resolve them, I get one instance of **TypeA** when resolving **InterfaceA**, and another instance when resolving **InterfaceB**. I expect to get the same instance for both resolves, but I am not.

I have also tried to add *.AsSingleton()* to the call, but it made no difference.

Am I doing something wrong, or does anyone have any ideas of doing this without adding a **TypeAFactory** or such that keeps track of the instances instead?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are seeing is by design.

To get the same instance for both interfaces you can create the instance yourself and register it for both interfaces:

```
var instanceOfA = new TypeA(...);
container.Register<InterfaceA>(instanceOfA);
container.Register<InterfaceB>(instanceOfA);
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I can only have one registered "InterfaceA" then, and not several. The last registered instance for that registration type will override the previous.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on my own with a quite ugly (but yet quite elegant) solution.

I create another, internal, instance of a *TinyIoCContainer*, and I register all my types with the actual *TinyIoCContainer.Current* by giving it a factory in the form of:

```
var container = TinyIoCContainer.Current;
var internalIoC = new TinyIoCContainer();
Dictionary<Type, Object> instances = new Dictionary<Type, Object>();

...

Func<TinyIoCContainer, NamedParameterOverloads, Object> factory = (TinyIoCContainer c, NamedParameterOverloads o) =>
{
    if (instances.ContainsKey(implementationType) == false)
    {
        // Create the instance only once, and save it to our dictionary.
        // This way we can get singleton implementations of multi-registered types.
        instances.Add(implementationType, internalIoC.Resolve(implementationType));
    }

    return instances[implementationType];
};

container.Register(registerType, factory, implementationType.FullName);
```

I'm sure there will be a few caveats with this solution, but I'm also sure I'll be able to figure out a workable fix for them, as things look right now.

Comment: Okay, seems like that did not work either. So I switched from using TinyIoC into Windsor instead. That worked much better.